# Vue + Vuetify on very old Chrome 36

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, babeljs

I'm a beginner on Vue and Vuetify and i'm trying to run a Vue + Vuetify app on a very old Chrome version ( Chrome 36 ). I just made the [Pollifil's settings](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/browser-support/) and apparently all JS works without console errors but CSS is causing problems in the visualization of some components. Trying use the Vuetify Grid component i'm getting some weired behavior:

[image]

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Check the applied styling against the capabilities of the browser (e.g. caniuse.com). Chrome 36 is a 6 year old browser, and it is likely to not support some things we take for granted.

Comment: In particular it might have only partial support for flexboxes and the like. You might have to apply your own css to get it to work. I would strongly recommend to update to a newer browser - be it Chrome or a different browser altogether.